# check in procedure in Visual Studio's Team System

Tags: tfs

In my team we're using Visual Studio's Team System as our source control.
I'd like to add some sort of a check in procedure, i.e., compiling the whole code before actually checking it in, and if the code does not compile, do not allow the check in.
I've googled the issue but probably used wrong keywords. 
I'd appreciate your help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Team Foundation Server 2010 supports gated builds.  That means you can shelve your changes in TFS, and have the build process check them in only when a build succeeds including those changes.

Comment: We're not on VS2010 yet :( Moreover - I'd like to prevent check ins that break the build, and not depend on the programmer's good will. Any suggestions for VS2008 ?

Comment: I don't think it depends on good will. A programmer can be completely unable to check-in code that would break the build if permissions are set appropriately. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd787631.aspx